# How to setOnItemClickListener for both AutoCompleteTextView and ListView which are in same activity?

Tags: android, listview, autocompletetextview, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to `setOnItemClickListener`  for `AutoCompleteTextView` and `ListView` in same activity, I have provided `OnItemClickListener` for both, when I do it both are not working. But when I provide it to any of one that is working good.

My Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
ListView listView;
Button button;
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button) ;
    autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    loadAutoCompleteTextViewData();


}

public void loadAutoCompleteTextViewData()
{
    DbHandler db = new DbHandler(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> BusLocationList = db.getBusLocation();
    ArrayAdapter<String> ListViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,BusLocationList);
    autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(ListViewAdapter);


}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    return true;

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.autoCompleteTextView) {
        String loc = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        DbHandler db = new DbHandler(getApplicationContext());
        List<String> BusRouteList = db.getBusRoute(loc);
        ArrayAdapter<String> lvAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, BusRouteList);
        listView.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    else if (view.getId() == R.id.listView) {
        //Intent will be used here after fixing the problem
    }       


}
```

}

Comment: Show your current code!

Comment: define `"not working."`

Comment: I added my code @Xenolion,@pskink

Comment: inside `onItemClick` you have to check `if (parent.getId() == R.id.listView) {...} else {...}`

Comment: @pskink I have tried `if(parent.getId() == R.id.listview)` but it is also not working.

Comment: so inside `onItemClick` add `Log.d(TAG, "parent " + parent);` what do you see on the logcat?

Comment: @pskink now it is working i just removed `else if(parent.getId()==R.id.autocompletelistview)` and used only `if(parent.getId()==R.id.listView)` now it is working as expected.Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: and what i wrote? `if (parent.getId() == R.id.listView) {...} else {...}` - do not use `R.id.autocompletelistview` in `else`

Comment: @pskink yes but by mistake i wrote `else if` instead of `else` sorry for that bro.